# disadvantages of subclassing ui components

Tags: eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I saw in eclipse articles saying that we can subclass Canvas and Composite.
And they have mentioned some points about subclassing the components.
Is that only applicable to SWT components or are they mentioning general
disadvantages of subclassing all the UI widgets? Please refer the site below.

[Writing Your Own Widget](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget/Writing%20Your%20Own%20Widget.htm)

Comment: What other widgets are you referring too? JFace objects are generally not widgets.

Comment: @ greg-449 SWT widgets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are saying you should only subclass `Canvas` and `Composite`. All other SWT widgets do actually check for subclassing and throw exceptions (although this can be overridden).

As the article says the widgets are generally platform specific so you would have to do an override for each platform. Since the widgets are not designed to be overridden the internal fields and methods are usually not accessible anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I got confused with SWT widgets. Are they talking only about SWT widget? Is this case would happen for other technology widgets as well? Like  Swing,etc.

Comment: @EnglishLearner I have no idea how other widget sets work, you will have to investigate each technology individually.